# How does $\langle 1/t\rangle $ denote a rate?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, mathematical-physics

I am going through an old paper of mathematical physics, and they claim $\langle 1/t\rangle$, where $\langle \cdot\rangle$ on an interval $[a,b]$ denotes the statistical average: $$\langle f\rangle = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f$$ is physically a rate. I can't see how the integral of the inverse of a time variable is a rate. Using the above definition, again on an interval $[a,b]$ we obtain $\langle 1/t\rangle  = \log(b/a)/(b-a)$ which looks unlike any "rate" I have ever seen.

Comment: I don't know the relation to physics, but that is the inverse of the [logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean).

Comment: That's how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_(mathematics)#Rate_of_change) defines rate.

Comment: @JMP My question is more of a physical one, in how does the given definition make sense as a rate in a physical context

Comment: Try asking at https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Rate is events over time, hence the dimension of a rate  is $1\over time$. Note that the integral is normalized  by the interval size, so it is actually an average.